# Speed up scipy quad integration (skip check_bounds and _asarray_validated?)

Tags: python, scipy, quad

I am calling `scipy.integrate.quad` about 500 times for different integrations (x and y values).
This takes a total of 46 seconds.
However, 19 seconds is used by `_evaluate._check_bounds` alone and `_prepare_x._asarray_validated` takes up another 11 seconds.

Can I somehow skip those checks and perform the same Operation in 16 seconds?

Comment: *"19 seconds is used by `_evaluate._check_bounds`"* That function is part of `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`.  Are you using `interp1d` in the functions that you are integrating?

Comment: yes, the function to integrate is the return of interp1d(x,y), where x and y are numpy vectors that describe my function (I don't have exact equations).

Comment: What do you use for the `kind` argument of `interp1d`?

Comment: I am not using the kind argument, so it is using linear

Comment: In that case, using `quad` and `interp1d` is overkill.  For example, for the definite integral over the full interval on which you have your x and y points, you could use [`numpy.trapz`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html).  It will give the same result as `quad` applied to the linearly interpolated data.

Comment: Have you considered wrapping directly around the fortran routine from quadpack?

Comment: To add to what @Warren Weckesser said, `np.interp` is much faster then interp1d for linear interpolation.

Comment: With numpy.trapz I can not define the integral limits. I assume it is interpolating over all x and y. My x and y may cover a little bit of a larger range than the integral limits

Answer (score 0):

Considerable performance gain is possible if you write your own wrapper for `qagpe` in python. `scipy.integrate.quad`wraps around the `qagpe` subroutine from [Quadpack](http://www.netlib.org/quadpack/qagpe.f).

About developing your own wrapper and calling shared libraries in Python. This is a helpful [link](https://publicwiki.deltares.nl/display/~baart_f/2011/10/23/Calling+fortran+from+python).

Answer (score 0):

[quadpy](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy) (one of my projects) vectorizes computation over the domains and the function values, so that should give you a substantial speed-up over calling `scipy.quad` many times.